# jQuery $.post not working correctly

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

For some reason... It's not getting any data from `script.php` and when I submit a form, there seems to be problem with submitting. When I hit submit button. it goes to `search.php?search=wasd` If I remove `$.post` function, there is no problem.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var form_data = ($(this).serialize());
    window.location.hash = form_data.replace('=','/');
    return false;
});

(function() {

window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Router: {}
};

App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        'search/:search': 'search',
        '*other': 'default'
    },

    index: function() {
        $(document.body).append("");
    },

    search: $.post("script.php", function(search) {
        $('#result').html(search);
    });

});

new App.Router();
Backbone.history.start();

})();
```

Comment: i do not know about backbone but i think search: expect function here so try to wrap post code in function..

Comment: looks file `search: $.post("script.php", function(search) {
        $('#result').html(search);
    });` should be `search: function(){ $.post("script.php", function(search) {
        $('#result').html(search);
    });}`

Comment: You are setting your `search` property to the result of calling the `$.post()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to assign search variable like this

```
search: function(){
 $.post("script.php", function(search) {
        $('#result').html(search);
    });
}
```

pass the data of your form thorugh $.post  if you want in following manner

```
search: function(){
 $.post("script.php", $("form").serialize(), function(search) {
        $('#result').html(search);
    });
}
```

and then try to print posted value on server side like this

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Right. I'm using var_dump & export in script.php. Seems to give me an empty array. Any ideas?

Comment: You should post values so you can get those at server side.. you are not passing a single value from $.post.. have a look at documentation of $.post at jQuery.com ... let me know if you have any queries

Comment: Well. I'm using a search so I must be passing something through... 
var_dump( $_POST );
var_export( $_POST );
print_r($_POST, 1);
and I get
array (size=0)
  empty
array ( ) as result

Comment: One more thing... It takes it from form, what if I was to refresh the page. There will be 0 results.

Comment: It is up to you how you want to deal with this behavior.. you can play with the response you got from script.php file in the success callback.